# In a linear system A*x=b, how to obtain A, from given x and b, symbolically in SymPy

Tags: linear-algebra, sympy

Consider the system of linear equations:   **A*x=b**

Knowing only the vector **b**, and the variables of interest **x**:

```
from sympy import Matrix, symbols

i, j, x1, x2 = symbols('i j x1 x2')

b = Matrix([i*j*x1 + j**2*x2,
                x2 +    i*x1])  

x = Matrix([x1, x2])
```

Is there any way to, symbolically and automatically, obtain **A**?

The returned values would be:

```
A == Matrix([[i*j, j**2],
             [  i,    1]])
```

(This is a simplified version of my problem, which has dozens of variables and symbols)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem:

```
from sympy import Matrix, symbols, Poly
import numpy as np

i, j, x1, x2 = symbols('i j x1 x2')

b = Matrix([i*j*x1 + j**2*x2,
                x2 +    i*x1])

x = Matrix([x1, x2])

# A = ?
```

One possible solution:

```
A = np.zeros((len(b),len(x))).tolist()
n_rows = len(A)
n_cols = len(A[0])

for i in range(n_rows):
    for j in range(n_cols):
        A[i][j] = Poly(b[i], x.free_symbols).coeff_monomial(x[j])
A = Matrix(A)
```

Answer (score 1):

You specify x and b to be vectors.
So you got:
A = [a1, a2; a3, a4]
x = [x1; x2]
b = [b1; b2]

The equation system is:
Ax = b or
a1 * x1 + a2 * x2 = b1  (eq1)
a3 * x1 + a4 * x2 = b2  (eq2)

This is a system with 2 equations and 4 unknowns (a1,a2,a3,a4).
So, no, there is no way to solve this to get a1,..,a4.
This doesn't have to do with any program/language, this is the linear algebra.

The only thing you can do is have constraints on your unknowns, eg for known a1, a3 and for x2!= 0 you can calculate a2 and a4.

Comment: I understand there are infinite solutions. But there could be a way to obtain one solution out of that domain of solutions, and then simplify it, to obtain the simplest solution, as in shown in my "A"

Comment: If we can do this by hand for simple cases, then there should be a more automatic way to do it for all cases.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a rudimentary approach and `solve` generally is not recommended. With some snooping around in the source, you could figure out which specific solve function it is running.

```py
from sympy import *

i, j, x1, x2 = symbols('i j x1 x2', real=True)

b = Matrix([[i * j * x1 + j ** 2 * x2],
            [x2 + i * x1]])

x = Matrix([[x1],
            [x2]])

a1, a2, a3, a4 = symbols("a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4", real=True)
A = Matrix([[a1, a2],
            [a3, a4]])

solution = solve(Eq(A * x, b), (a1, a2, a3, a4))
print(solution)

for key, value in solution.items():
    A = A.replace(key, value)
print(A)
```

Produces:

```
{a_3: (-a_4*x2 + i*x1 + x2)/x1, a_1: (-a_2*x2 + i*j*x1 + j**2*x2)/x1}
Matrix([[(-a_2*x2 + i*j*x1 + j**2*x2)/x1, a_2], [(-a_4*x2 + i*x1 + x2)/x1, a_4]])
```

Meaning that `a2` and `a4` can be any real number and then `a1` and `a3` will just be dependent on their choice.